# How to exclude special characters from select from where like - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to run this query, but it doesn't show anything:

```
select * 
from table 
where countries like '%Canada Italy France Belgica%'
```

But I have these values in my database:

```
Countries: "Canada, Italy, France, Bélgica"
```

If I do this query it works:

```
select * 
from table 
where countries like '%Canada, Italy, France, Bélgica%'
```

Comment: is countries nvarchar or varchar? And if the second works, what's the issue?

Comment: Your database has Accent-sensitive Collation. Perform the search and cast the condition as accent-insensitive. ` SELECT * FROM table WHERE countries Like '%conditions%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI`

Comment: @scsimon second works but i need to do query like first. and countries is varchar(max)

Comment: @Shawn Collate doesnt works for my query

Comment: @Raul I originally thought `é` was a unicode character, but it does fit within the Extended ASCII set which will fit into a `varchar()`.

Comment: In your database `countries` column, is it a list of countries and does it include commas?  If so, then `countries='Canada, Italy'` will never be `LIKE` 'Italy Canada' or 'Canada Italy` _(no comma)_.  You may be asking to resolve a problem that isn't really your problem.

Comment: Try `select * from table where countries COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI like '%Canada, Italy, France, Belgica%'`.

Comment: Are there any other Extended ASCII character besides `é`? If my previous collation doesn't work, you may have to find the Code Page of the server to get the right collation. The thing to remember is that `é` doesn't equal `e`. We are simply pretending that they are the same, but `e` is essentially a Latin character and won't necessarily map to some characters (like Asian or some Cyrillic characters). Your question really begins to get into the definition of what makes a character, which takes us to the realms of collation and code pages. Broad subject.

Comment: If you are going to be working with Extended ASCII or non-Latin characters, you'll want to read https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to have special handling for special characters.
You want to treat commas like they don't exist, and you want to treat 'é' the same as 'e'.
So replace all commas with empty string, and replace all 'é' with 'e', and then compare.

```
create table dbo.CountryTable ( Countries nvarchar(80) )

insert into CountryTable ( Countries ) values ( 'Canada, Italy, France, Bélgica' )

select * from CountryTable where 
  Replace( Replace(Countries, ',', ''), 'é', 'e' ) like '%Canada Italy France Belgica%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query with fixed name

```
select * from table where countries in ('Canada', 'Italy', 'France', 'Bélgica')
```

Or the following with wildcard

```
select * from table where countries like '%Canada%' or countries like 'France%'
```

Comment: It does not work. Because the value I'm looking for comes from a variable and I do not know how to separate the words (it can be 1 or 10)

Answer (score 0):

Swap your like clause around... so that you are seeing if anything in you list matches your column.

```
create table #myTable(countries nvarchar(64))
insert into #myTable
values
(N'Bélgica')
,(N'Canada')
,(N'France')


select * 
from #myTable
where 'Canada Italy France Belgica' like '%' + countries + '%'
```

If you literally have comma separated lists in the column... then you need to use a string splitter. There are dozens of examples on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In you table you may have column like ID, you can select those in

```
Where columnname IN (column1,column2...)



create table TEST001 (ID int,
countries nvarchar(100))

insert into TEST001
values
(1, 'Canada')
,(2, 'Italy')
,(3, 'France')
,(4, 'Belgica')


select * from TEST001 where ID in (1,2,3,4) 

select * from TEST001 where countries in ('Canada', 'Italy', 'France', 'Belgica')
```

Comment: Just an FYI here: You're creating an `nvarchar()` column for these characters. These aren't UNICODE values (well, technically they are). This is a `varchar()` column with an Extended ASCII character in it. They don't behave quite the same.